# How to use react-s3-uploader with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am new to reactjs want to upload image on s3, But don't know how it would work... And don't know where will I get the image path come from aws (in which function)?

Here is my react code

```
import ApiClient from './ApiClient';  // where it comes from?

function getSignedUrl(file, callback) {
  const client = new ApiClient();
  const params = {
    objectName: file.name,
    contentType: file.type
  };

  client.get('/my/signing/server', { params })   // what's that url?
  .then(data => {
    callback(data); // what should I get in callback?
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

My server file **Server.js**

```
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(Bluebird)

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'accessKey',
  secretAccessKey: 'secret',
  region: 'ap-south-1'
})

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: 'Bucketname'
  },
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
})

class S3Service {

  static getPreSignedUrl(filename, fileType, acl = 'public-read') {
    return new Bluebird(resolve => {
      const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 30000
      return resolve({
          signedRequest : s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
            Key: "wehab/"+filename,
            ContentType:"multipart/form-data",
            Bucket: config.get('/aws/bucket'),
            Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
          }),
          url : `https://${config.get('/aws/bucket')}.s3.amezonaws.com/wehab/${filename}`
        })
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First You need to create s3 bucket and attach these policies
 if bucket name is 'DROPZONEBUCKET' ( Bucket is globally unique )

Policy

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": [
               "s3:PutObject",
               "s3:GetObject"
           ],
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DROPZONEBUCKET/*"
       }
   ]
}
```

CORS config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>9000</MaxAgeSeconds>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Then run your node.js server and try to upload the file.

Once you select upload file it will call this  `getSignedUrl(file, callback)` function and it returns url.

Once you successfully get this URL you can upload the file.

Then file path is 
`https://s3.amazonaws.com/{BUCKET_NAME}/{FILE_NAME}`

ex.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/DROPZONEBUCKET/profile.jpeg
```

Modify API like this

```
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3();

var s3 = new Router({ mergeParams: true });

var params = {
    Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME', // add your s3 bucket name here
    Key: data.filename,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: data.filetype
  };

  s3Bucket.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Where should I keep the code for **Policy** and **CORS config**?? Front end or back end?? How this code can be used in `ReactS3Uploader`?

Comment: You have to keep Policy and CORS config on aws console ( AWS Console -> S3-> created bucket ->Permission tab ) then you can see bucket policy and cors config

Comment: Do you have aws console access? please login that and go to s3 section and select created s3 bucket then you can add those config

Comment: thanks for the help but still getting cross-origin error.. And added the config in aws console

Comment: Did you add those two configs ?

Comment: I have added cors configs... should I add policy as well?

Comment: And can you please explain me what is `MaxAgeSeconds`?

Comment: thanks for the help now last thing... I am getting response but `data: ""`... Or Will i found in other parameter?

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: please check the question... I have uploaded the image there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173821/discussion-between-niroshan-ranapathi-and-dark-knight).