# S3 multipart upload using API Gateway and Lambda Function

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipartform-data, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a React JS web application. From this application users can able to upload their photos/Videos into S3 bucket. And also the video size is pretty high (More than 300MB). So I decided to use **Multipart upload** method for uploading video files into S3 bucket. After looking about Multipart I understood this multipart concept but I can't implement it in my React project. So I came here with few questions about How multipart is working with React or someother Frontend.

Here is my question,

In my application I decided to use **AWS API Gateway and Lambda function** for uploading video files into S3 bucket. I am sending video files with API gateway from my React JS **POST** call. The question is, Actually where the multipart is performing or working whether it is in React code side or in Lambda function?

I created API Gateway with Content-Type : "multipart/form-data".

Main Question -> Is Multipart upload performing with React code side or in Lambda function to upload video files into S3 bucket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Multipart Upload, Lambda Function is not needed. The React app will upload directly to S3.

You should checkout something already built like [react-dropzone-s3-uploader-multipart](https://github.com/kpantic/react-dropzone-s3-uploader-multipart)

Comment: take a look at this other question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017765/how-to-use-react-s3-uploader-with-reactjs

Comment: Thanks for responding mostafazh. In uppy.io what is the serverUrl? is it presigned s3 bucket url or something else?

Comment: For extra security uppy requires a companion server (found here: https://uppy.io/docs/companion/) which you will need to provide to the example code.

Comment: I am just trying with react-s3-uploader-multipart npm package. But I keep getting the following error and I don't know where I made mistake.

   
              s3upload.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
    at S3Upload.push../node_modules/react-s3-uploader-multipart/s3upload.js.S3Upload.uploadToS3 (s3upload.js:64)
    at S3Upload.push../node_modules/react-s3-uploader-multipart/s3upload.js.S3Upload.uploadFile (s3upload.js:95)

Comment: Can you consider this question answered and start a new question for your coding issues?